# How to configure rules in prometheus file on docker in windows

Tags: docker, prometheus, docker-desktop, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I have prometheus container running on docker .
I want to add a rule file in which i precise the rules .

This is my prometheus.yml file under c://mypath , I use this path in the commande to run the container by adding -v

[image]

[image]

i have in the same path a file rules.yml , but every time when i launch prometheus i can't find the rules in rules tab .

can anyone please help on how to configure rules in prometheus.yml when prometheus is running on docker .

the same config just work for me when i m using a simple localhost and not  a container .

Thank you all !

Comment: This the commande i use it to run my prometheus container :   docker run -d --name prometheus -p 9123:9090 -v D:/prometheusVolumeDocker/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml bitnami/prometheus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only mounted `prometheus.yml` into `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` but not `rules.yml` into container.

Can you also mount your `rules.yml` into same path of container and try ?

`docker run -d --name prometheus -p 9123:9090 -v D:/prometheusVolumeDocker/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml  -v D:/prometheusVolumeDocker/rules.yml:/etc/prometheus/rules.yml bitnami/prometheus`

Answer (score 1):

Edit the prometheus.yml file and under the rule_files use this path instead

```
rule_files:
 - "/etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml"
```

and mount `rules.yml` in the docker command

`-v path\to\config\alert.yml:/etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml`